# Groupby datetime format and sum with value from other column (Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, pandas-groupby

I've been racking my brain about how to group by a time format column and sum it with the values of another column.

Every 4h we get information (entries and exit) and want to group by so we can have to sum of all entries and exit every 4h.

The issue is that if I apply the code below I get a weird result. The time isn't every 4h anymore and the sum is totally wrong. Does someone know where the issue is?

```
test = temp.groupby(['DATETIME'])['Entries_count'].sum().reset_index(name='Entries_count')
```

When I check the result. The time isn't every 4h anymore and the sum is totally wrong. Does someone know where the issue is?

ps: the time format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"

[image: Table to process]

[image: result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my case the groupby function doestn't work pretty well on time series.
Instead of using a groupby i switched to the reshape function which is more appropriate in this case.
The second issues concerning the improbable entries count is due to an anomaly in the dataset which when cleaned provide better results.

```
Distri = temp2.resample('4h').sum()
```

This fixed the issues :)